# Not able to access a class attribute

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I have a piece of code which is very simple though stuck for a silly yet difficult to figure out situation. Also i am a newbie to python, below is my code

```
class Function:
    def _init_(self):
        self.Name=""
        self.SubFunctions=[]
        self.IsSingle=False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test=Function()
    test.Name="testing"
    test.SubFunctions.append("param1") # gives an AttributeError: Function instance has no attribute 'SubFunctions'
```

If anybody can help me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misspelled [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__), it has **two** underscores at the start and end (for a total of 4 underscores). Your `_init_` method is never called.

Comment: BRAVO! you're the man!